# Disappearing Submenus

Tags: css

I have a menu which has sub-menus and I have defined it as such:

```
<nav class='top'>
    <li><a href="#">Lanky</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Links</a>
        <nav class='sub'>
            <li><a href="#">dead beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cafe feed</a></li>
        </nav>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Locks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Linger</a></li>
</nav>
```

I style it in such a way that the `sub nav` appears beside it's parent when on hover.

Problem is, I cannot click on those links. When I hover over the parent, the sub menu shows to the right and the `Locks` link displays beside the sub-menu (this is expexted). But once I `mouseOut` - say to try and click on `dead beef`, they disappear and the `Lock` link jumps back to its original position.

How do I make the `sub menu` persist to allow the mouse slide over to it?

Comment: What CSS do you have so far? Could you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?

Comment: Thanks for telling me about jsFiddle. I fixed the problem by styling the `<li>` objects that have ,`<ul>` descendants rather than depending on the class generated on the `<a>` link at runtime.

Comment: No problem. Yes, that sounds like exactly the correct fix. And take heed of @jeroen's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by addressing the list elements that had `nav` containers nested within. Many thanks to [thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) for pointing me to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - an amazing tool!

Here is the CSS...

```
nav { text-align: left; }
nav li { display: inline; text-align: center; }
nav a { display: inline-block; }
nav li { width: 95px; }
nav li nav { display: none; }
nav li:hover nav { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code compliant and accessible, you need to use the <ul> tags.

I suggest wrapping your <li> within the <ul> tags to fix your navigation errors - where you can also apply your class to the ul tag and there is no need for an additional div.

```
<ul class='top'>
<li><a href="#">Lanky</a></li>
<li> <a href="#">Links</a>
<li>
<ul class='sub'>
  <li><a href="#">dead beef</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cafe feed</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Locks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Linger</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 The permitted parent elements of a `li` are `ul`, `ol` and `menu` (wouldn´t recommmend that one...), see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: According to HTML5, there are some containers that act the same way as `ul` and are used for structure: `header`, `nav`, `section` and `footer`. All these have `display: block` appended to them so they can hold contents. And reading through the code is more intuitive with these.

Comment: I guess I need to quote something for that last comment: http://www.quora.com/In-HTML5-how-could-I-know-which-elements-are-generic-container-element

Comment: @Yasky: The point that's being made here is that `li` is not a valid child of `nav`. See: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Facero4&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0